# How to use fzf :Buffers/:Files commands from vim terminal buffer

Tags: terminal, plugin-fzf

When in (Vim) terminal mode, I can use  and then :e! fileName to open a file. Note that without the !, the following error message is displayed "E948: Job still running (add ! to end the job)".

How can I use the (awesome) fzf commands :Buffers, :Files etc., from the terminal buffer (as if they were run with an !)?

Comment: Why not switch to a non-terminal buffer first? I often split a terminal above my current file (the default behavior). If i want to edit a new file, i switch windows back to the file and start editing.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error E948 only occurs if `hidden` is not set. In this case vim does not allow to move a modified buffer out of view (lingua Vim: "abandon"). A terminal buffer with a running process (e.g. the shell) is handled like a modified file.

Add

```
set hidden
```

to your `vimrc`. This allows to abandon a modified buffer and a terminal with a running process.

See `:help hidden`.